# Decide where $f(x) = \frac{x +3}{x^2-1} $ for $x \neq -1,1$. Is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm a student studying math, and I'm going through some old exam problems and I have come across a set of questions that ask me to decide where a given function is continuous . At first glance it appears the example above is continuous everywhere as $x = -1,1$. Is it as simple enough just to say, or am I missing something, like a rigours theorem of some sort?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first glance should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The sum and product of continuous function is a continuous function, so it's enough to say that it will be continuous except for $x=-1, x=1$ since the function is undefined at those points

Comment: So you say $\frac{x +3}{x^2-1}$ is continuous because ${x +3}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ are continuous. Then the next question is, why is $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$   continuous?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-1$ & $g(x)=1$ is continuous, so $g/f$ is continuous where $f \ne 0$.